# How to calculate the median for a specific hour from a time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pivot

I have a df with information how many transfers have been made in the next 10 minutes. I would like to show which banks are the most popular at specific hours (I conclude that I will be able to show this thanks to the median). My pivot is like that:

```
     bank_name       bank1     bank2     bank3     bank4     
date
2019-11-03           102       105       78        81      
00:00

2019-11-03           108       100       103       77       
00:10

2019-11-03
00:20                108       134       55        27        
   ...                ...      ...       ...       ...       
2019-12-22
15:30                461       312       312       253      

2019-12-22           
15:40                396       361       376       229
```

Or regular df

```
date                  bank_name      transfers
2019-11-03 00:00      bank1          102
2019-11-03 00:00      bank2          105
2019-11-03 00:00      bank3          78
2019-11-03 00:00      bank4          81
2019-11-03 00:10      bank1          108
2019-11-03 00:10      bank2          100
...                   ...            ...
```

My expected out (I entered the median values ​​at random)

```
hour   bank_name   median
00     bank2       641
01     bank2       711
02     bank1       668
...     ...        ...
23     bank3       757
```

At the beginning I I would like to sum the values ​​from `2019-11-03 00:00, 00:10, 00:20, 00:30, 00:40, 00:50` and take it as a value `03 00`. I did it like this:

`df['date_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%d %H'))`

`df = df.set_index('bank_name').groupby([ 'bank_name', 'date_']).agg({'transfers':np.sum})`

... but I don't know what to do next. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: I don't see how your expected results relate to the median. The median across what? The median number of transfers across each 10 minutes interval in each hour?

Comment: I want to normalize df to hours (add transfer value from minutes to full hour, keeping days), and then calculate the median for each hour for each bank (I have 50 days so I have 50 observations about the amount of transfers from 15:00). The results that I published in the OP show which bank has the largest median at 01:00, 02:00 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd

df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.hour, 'bank_name'])['transfers'].median()
```

Comment: I guess it will be better to convert "date" type before.  As alternative you could use `df["date"].astype("M8[us]").dt.hour`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# median hourly transfer
hourly_transfers = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='H'), 'bank_name']).median()

# which bank has the highest median in each hour
idx = hourly_transfers.groupby('date')['transfers'].idxmax()

# the result
hourly_transfers.loc[idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you need to:

- Get sums by hour for each bank
- Extract the hour from the date
- Get the median for that hour across all dates

Something like this:

```
import datetime

df['date_hourly'] = df['date'].apply(lambda L: datetime(L.year, L.month, L.day, L.hour)) //  [From here][1]

df_hourly = df.groupby(['date_hourly', 'bank_name']).transfers.sum().reset_index()

df_hourly['hour'] = df_hourly.date_hourly.apply(lambda x: x.hour)

df_pivot = df_hourly.groupby(['hour', 'bank_name']).transfers.median().reset_index()
```